# Function call in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code in python3 and I don't know why the first call doesn't have an error but the second one has?

```py
def one_star_type(a, b, *more):
    print(a + b + sum(more))
    print(type(more))  # <class 'tuple'>

one_star_type(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

def one_star_type(a, b, **c):
    print(a, b, c)
    print(type(c))

def should_set_value(a, *, b=2, c=5):
    print(a, b, c)

one_star_type(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

//one_star_type(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
//TypeError: one_star_type() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given
//15
//<class 'tuple'>
```

Comment: `**c` means that the remaining arguments have to be keyword arguments, because `c` will be a dictionary, not a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

The `**c` requires keyword arguments, and returns a dictionary. Use `*c` instead.